# Could not find or load main class org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to run program to connect Kafka with MQ using the command  below from Ubuntu but getting the below error

Error:

> Could not find or load main class org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone

Command:

> `CLASSPATH=<connector-root-directory>/target/kafka-connect-mq-sink-<version>-jar-with-dependencies.jar ./bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties ~/mq-sink.properties`

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify the classpath.

In the `config/connect-standalone.properties` file you can declare a `plugin.path` property ( e.g: `plugin.path=/usr/local/share/java` ). Then, you have to place the jar on that path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with running MongoDb connector on Windows. Whenever I was running `bin\connect-standalone.sh`, I was getting the same error. I noticed that there was a `bin\windows\connect-standalone.bat`, but it was empty. So I copied the content from `connect-distrubted.bat` and replaced all occurences of `distributed` with `standalone`. Now running the bat successfully starts the connector, even though there are some exceptions thrown during start-up, e.g. `could not get type for name org.easymock.IArgumentMatcher`